# open file and remove first tag

Tags: php, file, tags

This would be a HTML file:

```
<li class="msgln">hello</li><li class="msgln">hi</li><li class="msgln">hey</li>
```

And php script:

```
$fp = fopen("file.html", 'a');
....
fclose($fp);
```

How to remove first `<li class="msgln">hello</li>`?

Content in `<li>` is dynamically changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work even if the first `li` would contain other nested `li`s:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<li class="msgln">hello</li><li class="msgln">hi</li><li class="msgln">hey</li>
');

$root = $doc->documentElement;
$p = $doc->documentElement->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes;
$li = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li')->item(0);
$li->parentNode->removeChild($li);

$html = '';
foreach ($root->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $html .= $doc->saveXML($child);
}
echo $html;

?>
```

using [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/511300) may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` to achieve this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('file.html');
$html = preg_replace('#^<li[^>]*>[^<]+</li>#i', '', $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the file is exactly as described then you could use strip_tags() such like:

```
$fp = fopen("file.html", 'a');
$content = fread($fp);
$content = strip_tags($content);
fclose($fp);
```

Alternatively you could use regular expressions but this would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fp = fopen("file.html", 'a');
$content = fread($fp);
$text = preg_replace( "/<li.+?>.+?<\/li>/is", "", $content, 1 );
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (without regex)

```
//string contains the file value
$string = '<li class="msgln">hello</li><li class="msgln">hi</li><li class="msgln">hey</li>';

$tag = '</li>';

$lis = explode($tag, $string);

if(count($lis) > 0) {
    unset($lis[0]);
    $string = implode($tag, $lis);
}
```